# declaring a json array as a param on post in grape

Tags: arrays, json, ruby-grape

I am trying to post a json array of objects like:

```
[
 {
  "name": "name1",
  "source": "source",
  "description": "description1"
 },
 {
  "name": "name2",
  "source": "source",
  "description": "description2"
 }
]
```

Since I need to declare all needed params in grape, I am having an issue declaring this array since it does not have a name I can reference it by. Any idea if there is a way to declare this array?

Comment: the issue is resolved here: https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/issues/1730